# Arduino writing speed to screen

Tags: c++, arduino, gps

I can't get my GPS to update the speed. It displays the text, and if I take the GPS speed out of the location update loop it shows the current speed once, then fails to update. Any idea?

```
void loop() {
  while (serial_connections.available()) {
    gps.encode(serial_connections.read());
    if (gps.location.isUpdated()) {
      DText = Serial.println(gps.speed.mps());
      DSat = Serial.println(gps.satellites.value());
    }
    display.clearDisplay();  // clears last number
    display.display();  // writes clear to screen
    display.setCursor(10, 5);  //Set drawing posision
    display.print(DText);  // what to draw
    display.setCursor(35, 5);
    display.print(" MPS");
    display.setCursor(10, 18);
    display.print(DSat);
    display.setCursor(35, 18);
    display.print(" Sat");
    display.display(); // writes to the screen
    delay (50);
  }
}
```

Comment: Reformat your code please. There is at least one `}` missing

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It's not really missing it's below 75lines of commented out code.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If so, please provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it shows the current speed once, then fails to update. Any idea?

Your sketch is spending all its time updating the display and waiting.  Here's what's happening:

1)  When one character is available, it gets read and passed to `encode`.

2)  Then it updates the display, which takes some amount of time.  You didn't give us the whole program nor identify the hardware, so I cant really say how long it takes.

3)  Then it waits 50ms.  During this time, GPS characters continue to arrive.  They will be stored in the input buffer until `read()` is called, *OR* until 64 characters have been stored.  THEN THEY WILL BE DROPPED.

At 9600 (I am guessing), 50 characters could have arrived.  Now the input buffer is almost full.

4)  The `while` loop test executes again, and a second character is read and parsed (step 1), the display is updated (no new info is available, step 2), and it waits another 50ms.

After 15ms, the input buffer is full, and the Arduino begins ignoring characters.  When the 50ms delay completes, 35 characters have been lost (at 9600).

This prevents a successful parse of the received (partial) NMEA sentences, and the speed will not get updated.  The sketch will continue to update the display with old information, and then wait some more, which causes more character loss.

The loop structure needs to be reworked so that the display is only updated when new information is available, and you should never use delay:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h> ???
LiquidCrystal display;     ???

#include <NMEAGPS.h>

NMEAGPS gps;
gps_fix fix;

//  Here are three different ways to connect the GPS:
#define gpsPort Serial1

//#include <AltSoftSerial.h>
//AltSoftSerial gpsPort; // two specific pins required (8 & 9 on an UNO)

//#include <NeoSWSerial.h>
//NeoSWSerial gpsPort( 3, 4 );


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin( 9600 );
  gpsPort.begin( 9600 );
}

void loop()
{
  // Read and parse any available characters from the GPS device
  if (gps.available( gpsPort )) {

    // Once per second, a complete fix structure is ready.
    fix = gps.read();

    Serial.print( F("Speed: ") );
    float speed = 0.0;
    if (fix.valid.speed) {
      speed = fix.speed_kph() * 1000.0 / 3600.0;
      Serial.print( speed );
    }
    Serial.println();

    Serial.print( F("Sats: ") );
    if (fix.valid.satellites)
      Serial.println( fix.satellites );
    Serial.println();

    //  Update the display ONCE PER SECOND

    display.clearDisplay();  // clears last number
    display.display();  // writes clear to screen
    display.setCursor(10, 5);  //Set drawing posision
    if (fix.valid.speed)
      display.print( speed );  // what to draw
    display.setCursor(35, 5);
    display.print(" MPS");
    display.setCursor(10, 18);
    if (fix.valid.satellites)
      display.print( fix.satellites );
    display.setCursor(35, 18);
    display.print(" Sat");
    display.display(); // writes to the screen
  }
}
```

This uses my [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS) library.  It is smaller, faster, more reliable and more accurate than all other GPS libraries.  Even if you don't use it, you should read the related pages about [choosing a serial port](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/extras/doc/Installing.md#2-choose-a-serial-port) and [troubleshooting](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/extras/doc/Troubleshooting.md).

NeoGPS, AltSoftSerial and NeoSWSerial are all available from the Arduino IDE Library Manager, under the menu **Sketch -> Include Library -> Manage Libraries**.

Comment: Thanks your post was awesome. I learned a lot and it ended up leading me to get the screen to update the GPS and serial monitor. 

And to add the screen is SSD1306, and the GPS is an NEO 6. Going into a Metro Mini.

Comment: @williamyocom, Glad to help! Since it's going on the Mini, NeoGPS will really help you save some of that precious RAM. Using the F macro on double-quoted prints will also help. You may want to look at the u8g2 library. It can also save a lot of RAM, at the expense of a little execution time. And... if this solved your problem, please press that green triangle on my answer to "accept" it. Otherwise, it lingers here, forever haunting me... :-) Thanks.